# mysql design for sharing content between friends

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, database-design, relational-database

I'm developing a social network like Facebook but its kind of specific to the users who can join. anyway i have to do a Facebook style wall for each user where he/she can post content.
(I'm at the first step with posting just text, photos and video are coming).

Now the user should has the ability to define with whom to share the post, 'friends' 'all' 'just me'.

Each user can belong to an institute where also has own wall with posts. the institute should also be able to share posts with user groups.

So my question:

How do I have to design the MySQL tables for this job?

What i have is:

- users table :    `user_id`, ....
- friends table:   `id`, `user_id`, `friend_id`, `status`
- posts table:     `post_id`, `user_id`, `post_title`, `post_content`, `post_date`
- comments table:  `comment_id`, `user_id`, `post_id`, `comment_text`, `comment_date`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this. A simple approach is to create a table that defines what visibility types you can have for each post:

```
CREATE TABLE PostVisibilityType
(
    visibility_id, //primary key
    visibility_type // friend, all, private etc...
)
```

Update the schema for the post table to have a `visibility_id` which will indicate what type of visibility this post has i.e. "Friends only", "Private" etc

```
posts table: post_id, user_id, visibility_id,...
```

For the institutions, you will need to setup a table to define your groups, so a UserGroup table and assign the id of that table to the User table, so you can tag which group a user belongs to. For the institutions you can have a visibility type called "Group" which will allow only users in that group to see the posts.

When a user logs in and wants to see a post belong to a User X, you will have to pick the id associated to that post and determine what the visibility is. If it is private, block. If it is friend, determine if logged in User is a friend. If 'all', allow to see.

Another thing you might want to consider is to use a graph database like Neo4j. They allow these types of relationships/associations to be specified very easily.